Converse of Scherk–Segre theorem on the number of vertices of a convex space curve
It is well known that any smooth simple closed convex curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ that meets no plane in more than 4 points has exactly 4 vertices, i.e., points of vanishing torsion; here "convex" means that the curve lies on the boundary of its convex hull. This result, as mentioned for example by Pohl in On a theorem related to the four-vertex theorem, goes back to the work of Scherk and Segre in the 1930s.
I was wondering about the other direction:
Question. If $\gamma$ is a simple closed convex curve with (nonvanishing curvature and) exactly 4 vertices, does it then follow that no plane intersects it in more than 4 points?
Note that if $\gamma$ lies on $\mathbb{S}^{2}$, then points of vanishing torsion correspond to critical points of the geodesic curvature. So to find a counterexample it would suffice to construct a spherical curve with exactly 4 critical points of geodesic curvature that does not satisfy the given intersection condition.

The answer is no. To construct counterexamples, start with a double spiral in $\mathbf{S}^2$ which is centered at the North Pole and tangent to the equator at its end points. Then glue this segment to its antipodal reflection. This yields a simple closed curve in $\mathbf{S^2}$ with exactly $4$ inflections, and one vertex between every pair of inflections. Thus it has exactly $4$ vertices, but it intersects any plane containing the $z$-axis many times.

